# Accessing python file from another computer

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, artificial-intelligence

My web product is on my Server. It does not have GPU. I need to run few AI algorithms and display that output on my website. I want to run that code on my another system which consists of GPU . Is that possible If yes? can you please suggest?

Edit: GPU and CPU are on the same server. Right now Algorithms are not been hosted on any server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to add more detail if you want a good answer. What kind of web server are you running? Is the system with the GPU on the same network? Do you already have a service running on that GPU server to handle requests to your AI algorithm? If not, what kind of framework or system are you using to run your AI algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is kinda possible and let me explain. first, you should have the python script that you wanna run on your computer with a GPU available. second, you need to code a python based server that listens for incoming connections, when a connection connects to the server, the server executes the python file, saves the output through piping and then returns the output to the connection. this can be deployed with website easily. you can use php sockets to send and receive data to your python server.

Idea : Python Server Running On Specific Port Listening For Incoming Connections ==> A Connection Hits The Server ==> The Servers Runs The Code That contains the AI Of Yours, Saves The Outputs and sends back the output to the client.

Comment: I would send a path of folder which is on CPU then can GPU can access that file?

Comment: yes. you can send it or it can be statically defined in the server. it is your choice.

Comment: So, It is like, I am using cherrypy to send requests and get responses. The code in the second machine needs to be run on virtualenv.. How to connect these dots?

Comment: okay. first, you need to setup the python server on your machine containing the GPU and the python code that needs to be run. using the sockets library in python, you can code the server and listen for incoming connections. when a connection comes from your web interface, the python server reads the data, executes the python code on the gpu and returns the response to the web interface. if you need further explanation and help in the code or connecting the dots, just reply and i will explain way more deeper